# If $G$ normalises $H$ then $G$ normalises $C_{S_n}(H)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

**Claim :** If $G \le S_n $ normalises $H$ then $G$ normalises $C_{S_n}(H)$

**Definitions :** $C_{S_n}(H) = \{\sigma \in S_{n} \mid h\sigma = \sigma h, \forall h \in H \} $

**My attempt :** As $G$ normalises $H$ that means any $\sigma \in G, H\sigma = \sigma H$. To prove $\sigma C_{S_n}(H) \sigma^{-1} = C_{S_n}(H) $. Let $k \in C_{S_n}(H) $ now it is easy to see that $\sigma k \sigma^{-1}  = g_1\sigma^{-1} = g_2, \text{where}  g_2 \in C_{S_n}(H) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $X$, then you can check easily that $C_X(H) \unlhd N_X(H)$ (even $N_X(H)/C_X(H)$ can be homomorphically embedded in Aut$(H)$, but that is irrelevant here.).

Now, if $G$ is another subgroup of $X$ that normalizes $H$, that is $G \subseteq N_X(H)$, then, since $C_X(H)$ is normal in $N_X(H)$, $G \subseteq N_X(C_X(H))$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g\in G, h\in H, x\in C(H)$, we show that $gxg^{-1}$ commutes with $h$, we have:

$gxg^{-1}h=gx(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1}$ since $G$ normalizes $H$, $g^{-1}hg\in H$ and since $x\in C(G)$, we have $gx(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1}=g(g^{-1}hg)xg^{-1}=hgxg^{-1}$.